# How do I merge data frames with matching characters in the object name?

Tags: r, dataframe, names, rbind

I have a bunch of individual dataframes that have names like `day01_01_1of2`, `day01_01_2of2`, `day01_02_1of2`, etc.

And I want to create a conditional statement that will find data-frames with the first characters matching (ie. `day01_01`) and bind the rows together. I cannot find any way to do this.

I can manipulate the data from a list in R:
[Image of the lists from Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Gsw.png)

or from individual data frames in the global environment

```
ls()
 [1] "day01_01_1of2" "day01_01_2of2" "day01_02_1of2" "day01_02_2of2" "day01_03_1of2"
 [6] "day01_03_2of2" "day01_04_1of2" "day01_04_2of2" "day01_05_1of2" "day01_05_2of2"
[11] "day01_06_1of2" "day01_06_2of2" "day01_07_1of2" "day01_07_2of2" "day01_08_1of2"
[16] "day01_08_2of2" "day01_09_1of2" "day01_09_2of2" "day01_10_1of2" "day01_10_2of2"
```

I am looking for any solutions whether they be in the list or outside of the list.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: [Don't ever create d1, d2, d3, ..., dn in the first place. Create a list d with n elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451)

Comment: Good. Keep as a *single* list rather than *many* objects. And since they are named elements, simply use the extract method `[`: `mylistofdfs[grep("day01_01", names(mylistofdfs))]`. Then `rbind`, `cbind`, or `merge` on subsetted list. No need to traverse global environment with `ls`, `get`, or `mget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a split of the vector with substring of vector

```
str1 <- ls()
lst1 <- split(str1, sub("_[^_]+$", "", str1))
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) do.call(rbind, mget(x, inherits = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. I am getting an error: Error: value for ‘day01_01_1of2’ not found 
6.
stop(gettextf("value for %s not found", sQuote(x)), call. = FALSE) 
5.
(function (x) 
stop(gettextf("value for %s not found", sQuote(x)), call. = FALSE))("day01_01_1of2") 
4.
mget(x) 
3.
do.call(rbind, mget(x)) 
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.
lapply(lst1, function(x) do.call(rbind, mget(x)))

Comment: Is there a way to do this same thing with all the data frames in a list (ie. str1 would actually be a list of all the data frames)?

Comment: @K8Otter `ls()` returns all the objects created in the global env.  If you have only created data.frame, then the `mget`  will get the value of those in a `list`.   I didn't understand your question proprely

Comment: Essentially, can the third line be adapted such that it is using rbind on dataframes in a list rather than in the global env

Comment: May be you want `lapply(lst1, function(sublst) do.call(rbind, sublst))`